# Why is Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype) so common, which seemingly introduces unnecessary indirection?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Now the Child's prototype isn't actually a copy/reference of the Parent's prototype but rather the Child's prototype's prototype is. Parent prototype properties cannot even be overriden using the practical `Child.prototype.foo = blah` syntax, just shadowed, which seems like a waste of memory at best.

Why the added level of indirection instead of just using a flat copy/reference?

Comment: What would a flat copy look like?

Comment: Yes, they cannot be overridden. That they're only shadowed is the whole purpose of this construct. Imagine what would happen otherwise if you had multiple subclasses.

Comment: @Bergi, no they would not be overriden, merely shadowed

Comment: But to answer my own question: probably because with a copy changes on the Parent prototype wouldn't propagate to the children any longer and with a reference changing the children's prototype would affect the Parent prototype, which is undesired. Right? Still effectively using  the Child's prototype's prototype seems like a weird extra level of indirection.

Comment: @hubzkq1: Yes, that sounds about right. With a copy, changes on the parent would not be propagated (and there is no more inheritance), with a direct reference any change would affect the parent prototype directly which is undesired.

Comment: *"Parent prototype properties cannot even be overriden"* That's the whole point. A change to a child class should not affect the parent. Just like Bergi mentioned.

Comment: @FelixKling no I mean when you do `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)` where `Parent.prototype.foo` exists and then doing `Child.prototype.foo = blah`, then actually still `Child.prototype.prototype.foo == Parent.prototype.foo` even if `Parent.prototype.foo != blah` hence the original `foo` didn't get overriden, it is just shadowed

Comment: @FelixKling basically there are two points that are equally important it seems, like I said in my own answer. Because "Parent prototype properties cannot even be overriden" can be guaranteed with a copy too. Sometimes asking a question helps answering it I guess ^^

Comment: @Bergi, right, makes sense now

Comment: Ah yes, I was focused on the referencing part only :)

Comment: The easiest way to explain is to say a Cat is an Animal but an Animal isn't always a Cat. As for shadowing; you use this to deliberately completely override Parent with different behavior or extend Parent behavior. Not shadowing means you'll leave implementation up to the Parent. More detailed examples (although not a very good one) about extending can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941